# How to turn iptables stateless?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I'm running a Linux server that - from time to time - faces heavy load and the conntrack table overflows. Since it's iptables firewall ruleset is very simple I'd like to turn it to stateless mode. I know that iptables can operate in stateful connection tracking mode and in a stateless mode.

My firewall rules are all in place I'm pretty sure that they are stateless but my question is how can I verify that the firewall is really operating in stateless mode?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to specify some iptables rules to prevent packets to be conntracked :

```
iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -j NOTRACK
iptables -t raw -I OUTPUT -j NOTRACK
```

Comment: actually it is "-t raw" and not "-t RAW" but that was the missing pice. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't answer your question since it was "how can I *verify* that the firewall is really operating in stateless mode" actually.

Comment: Please excuse my wording. My english is not perfect, but that was exactly the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 6):

`cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack` shows all connection tracking.

So, if it's stateless, the output of the above command should be empty.

(Alternatively, use `cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack`)

Answer (score 5):

Install [conntrack](http://linux.die.net/man/8/conntrack), and look at the output.  I am pretty sure if you are stateless no connections will be displayed.