# In K8s network, why UDP packets are dropped by kernel?

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, kubernetes, nat

1. In Azure I have two k8s services: serviceA and serviceB.  serviceA's type is LoadBalancer, and set externalTrafficPolicy=Local
2. Client sends UDP packets to serviceA, serviceA transfer them to serviceB by code in user space, serviceB's pod is expected to send response packets to client directly.
3. serviceA's one pod (podA) and serviceB's one pod (podB) may be arranged in same host.
4. In order to do that, I have an initial container in podB to set a SNAT rule in host. The SNAT rule is: change source IP of UDP packet (podB sent out) from its pod IP to load balancer's floating IP. e.g.

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -p udp -s 10.224.0.157 --sport 9999 -j SNAT --to-source 20.225.34.72:9999
```

5. If podA and podB are in same host, the packets are dropped, otherwise they are sent out.

[The iptables rules in host (execute iptables-save)](https://github.com/guofeiyu2022/commonfiles/blob/main/iptables-az.txt)

[The trace result by nettrace tool](https://github.com/guofeiyu2022/commonfiles/blob/main/nettrace.txt)

Tried in Azure and local K8s, the result are same. If podA and podB are in same host, the packets are dropped. I want to expect the packets are sent to clients like they are sent by podB in a separate host.

Comment: Wild guess: when client sends to service A, a Netfilter conntrack entry is created and also includes NAT properties to reach pod A. When you attempt to create again a conntrack entry for pod B to reach back the client as if it were the reply from pod A, this would create a conntrack collision and the packet is thus dropped instead.

Comment: This can be overcome by "instantiating" conntrack using conntrack zones, but integration is probably not easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please introduce more about conntrack zone settings for my case? or Can I just disable the conntrack for that inbound NAT for pod A?

Comment: I can give you Q/A where I made answers about it (not for your specific case, but so you understand what it's for). I won't attempt to give an answer to your question because the Kubernetes environment makes it too complex: https://serverfault.com/questions/741104/iptables-redirect-works-only-for-first-packet/949460#949460 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323758/iptables-redirect-all-udp-packets-including-established/494972#494972 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553334/setting-up-udp-packets-to-two-different-destinations-using-iptables-and-prerouti/553707#553707

Comment: And no you cannot disable conntrack: it's what allows  to perform stateful NAT. Then stateless NAT requires something else than iptables: tc or nftables. Maybe nftables would do for stateless nat (+ conntrack disabled) if it attempts to not clash with iptables and Kubernetes. Check this documentation: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Mangling_packet_headers . Else you might want to reconsider your whole architecture to not have to do all of this.

Comment: Thank you! I added below setting and now the dropping was gone in Azure K8s:
 "iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p udp -s 10.224.0.157 --sport 9999 -j CT --zone 1"

But in my local K8s it still doen't work, even if I set 'NOTRACK' for inbound dnat. Is there possible other reason that due to packets drop?